# Why webpack-dev-middleware provides `publicPath` configuration?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

From the [readme of webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware), there is a `publicPath` configuration:

```
publicPath: "/assets/",
// public path to bind the middleware to
// use the same as in webpack
```

But I'm not sure why there is such a configuration since there is already a same one in `webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary for Hot Module Replacement to know where to load the hot update chunks.